# Validation rule to restrict picklist but still allow others to edit the record

Tags: validation-rule, validation

I have a validation rule that restricts a picklist value so that only two users can select it. This is working well but the problem we're facing is that now no one, except those two users, can edit the record and everyone should be able to edit it, they just shouldn't be able to choose that value.

This is the validation rule I'm using now:

```
AND( 
    INCLUDES( Request_Reasons__c , "Accounting Adjustments"),
    $User.Email!="xxx@xxx.com",
    $User.Email!="xxx@xxx.com"
)
```

Is there any way I can modify it so that it allows every user to edit the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add in a condition to your validation rule so that it only prevents others from *changing* that picklist *to your target value*.

That is to say, add `ISCHANGED(Request_Reasons__c)` into your `AND()`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked!